# Is Steven J. Miller's "research" on election fraud sound? And was he paid for it?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, applied-mathematics

I recently encountered the following piece regarding alleged massive voter fraud in Pennsylvania:

https://justthenews.com/sites/default/files/2020-11/Miller_DeclarationAndAnalyisPA_GOP_BallotRequestData_2020_Final.pdf

My question is:  Do other professional mathematicians find the reasoning in this research compelling?

Comment: "Was xxx paid" is absolutely off-topic here. As regards the first question, having a look at this pdf the whole thing seems at odds with any research-level math and it's not the role of this site to include discussions about this.

Comment: This is certainly strange. But you don't need MathOverflow for this. Write a blog post or something.

Comment: “Is this paper correct?” is generally off-topic, and I see no reason to make an exception here. “Was he paid?” seems irrelevant: Would you trust the results more or less if he was a Biden supporter being paid or a Trump supporter volunteering?

Comment: It’s not research, just a freshman stats-level analysis of some given data that doesn’t even purport to seriously try to answer any of the questions of interest. Specifically there are (1) no attempt to measure the number of missing ballots from the other party (2) no attempt to discuss prior expectations for numbers of missing ballots (3) no discussion of a huge potential for response bias (4) no effort to correctly interpret confidence intervals, all of which would certainly be needed in any attempt to actually answer the questions at which the affidavit is aimed.

Comment: In regard to the close votes, did anyone read *The Glass Bead Game* by Hesse? There's a moral about the danger of academics staying in an ivory tower and not getting involved in the world.

Comment: @NikWeaver , you do realize that this is not an American website? If this question is allowed, we would have to allow questions about any election in the world, and there are a lot of elections in the world.

Comment: I agree that questions of moral turpitude don't belong here, but I also agree with Nik that if despots around the world are going to use mathematicians and mathematical reasoning to invalidate millions of votes we have a responsibility to collectively verify or reject the work to th best of our ability. Millions of peoples voting rights hang in the balance, and it wouldn't take an undue amount of effort on our part IMO. Upvoting and voting to reopen, with an edit to remove the question about money. I even think opening to copy-paste Kevin's comment as an answer then re-closing would be better.

Comment: I suggest posting your question at sceptics stack exchange site.

Comment: Or possibly at CrossValidated

Comment: I believe this question deserves to be answered but not on MO, just like debunking misuses of mathematics is appropriate for Notices of AMS (and NAMS did publish such  in the past) but not for JAMS. For instance: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com would be a much better fit. @todd-trimble: Would you be willing to migrate this (I think important) question to a more appropriate site?

Comment: That thing is hoax. The author states that he's 18 of age  and got his BS in 1996, 24 years ago. You do not need the expertise at MO to smell something fishy.   Coincidently, there is a White House adviser by the name of Steve Miller.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: There is a real mathematician (a number theorist) at Williams College whose name is Steven J. Miller, he indeed got his PhD in Princeton in 2002. I do not see any reasons to doubt that he wrote the affidavit.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  My bad. Sorry

Comment: Even Steven J. Miller's CV is in LaTeX:

https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/math/SJMillerCV.pdf

which suggests that even if he did sign off that affidavit, he didn't write the statistical analysis himself.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: I would not be so sure: He teaches undergrad stat classes at Williams, so he could have done this himself. As Kevin says (and I agree), the affidavit is at freshman stats-level analysis level.

Comment: To replace my previous comment, which was not clear: I have contacted Dr. Miller at Williams, and he has confirmed that he signed the affidavit. I agree that it looks unlikely that he personally composed the text, something he neither confirmed nor denied to me, though he's certainly well qualified to assess its contents.

Comment: https://liorpachter.wordpress.com/2020/11/22/williams-math-professor-investigating-voter-fraud-in-pennsylvania-finds-no-evidence/